# Elasticsearch - find closest number when scoring results

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I need a way to match the closest number of an elasticsearch document.

I'm wanting to use elastic search to filter quantifiable attributes and have been able to achieve hard limits using **range** queries accept that results that are outside of that result set are skipped. I would prefer to have the closest results to multiple filters match.

```
const query = {
  query: {
    bool: {
      should: [
        {
          range: {
            gte: 5,
            lte: 15
          }
        },
        {
          range: {
            gte: 1979,
            lte: 1989
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
const results = await client.search({
  index: 'test',
  body: query
})
```

Say I had some documents that had year and sales. In the snippet is a little example of how it would be done in javascript. It runs through the entire list and calculates a score, then based on that score it sorts them, at no point are results filtered out, they are just organized by relevance.

```js
const data = [
  { "item": "one", "year": 1980, "sales": 20 },
  { "item": "two", "year": 1982, "sales": 12 },
  { "item": "three", "year": 1986, "sales": 6 },
  { "item": "four", "year": 1989, "sales": 4 },
  { "item": "five", "year": 1991, "sales": 6 }
]

const add = (a, b) => a + b


const findClosestMatch = (filters, data) => {
 const scored = data.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    // add the score to a copy of the data
    _score: calculateDifferenceScore(filters, item)
  }))
  // mutate the scored array by sorting it
  scored.sort((a, b) => a._score.total - b._score.total)
  return scored
}

const calculateDifferenceScore = (filters, item) => {
  const result = Object.keys(filters).reduce((acc, x) => ({
    ...acc,
    // calculate the absolute difference between the filter and data point
    [x]: Math.abs(filters[x] - item[x])
  }), {})
  // sum the total diffences
  result.total = Object.values(result).reduce(add)
  return result
}

console.log(
  findClosestMatch({ sales: 10, year: 1984 }, data)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```

I'm trying to achieve the same thing in elasticsearch but having no luck when using a **function_score** query. eg

```
const query = {
  query: {
    function_score: {
      functions: [
        {
          linear: {
            "year": {
              origin: 1984,
            },
            "sales": {
              origin: 10,
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
const results = await client.search({
  index: 'test',
  body: query
})
```

There is no text to search, I'm using it for filtering by numbers only, am I doing something wrong or is this not what elastic search is made for and are there any better alternatives?

Using the above every document still has a default score, and I have not been able to get any filter to apply any modifiers to the score.

Thanks for any help, I new to elasticsearch links to articles or areas of the documentation are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea, you're just missing a few fields in your query to make it work.

It should look like this:

```
{
      "query": {
        function_score: {
            functions: [
                {
                    linear: {
                        "year": {
                            origin: 1984,
                            scale: 1,
                            decay: 0.999
                        },
                        "sales": {
                            origin: 10,
                            scale: 1,
                            decay: 0.999
                        }
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The `scale` field is mandatory as it tells elastic how to decay the score, without it the query just fails.

The `decay` field is not mandatory, however without it elastic does not really know how to calculate the new score to documents so it will end up giving a default score only to documents in the range of origin + scale which is not useful for us.

[source docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html).

- I also recommend you limit the result size to 1 if you want the top scoring document, otherwise you'll have add a sort phase (either in elastic or in code).

EDIT: (AVOID NULLS)

You can add a filter above the functions like so:

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "bool": {
                                "filter": [
                                    {
                                        "bool": {
                                            "must": [
                                                {
                                                    "exists": {
                                                        "field": "year"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "exists": {
                                                        "field": "sales"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match_all": {}
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "functions": [
                {
                    "linear": {
                        "year": {
                            "origin": 1999,
                            "scale": 1,
                            "decay": 0.999
                        },
                        "sales": {
                            "origin": 50,
                            "scale": 1,
                            "decay": 0.999
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Notice i have a little hack going on using `match_all` query, this is due to filter query setting the score to 0 so by using the `match all` query i reset it back to 1 for all matched documents.

This can also be achieved in a more "proper" way by altering the functions, a path i choose not to take.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and sorry for the late reply. I think my example did not tell the whole story of my data set, I gave a simple example that I thought covered my issue, but in actuality it is possible that a document does not have a year or sales set, when I run your query I get results that don't have the attributes set, is there any way I can filter them out prior to sorting? I was trying to add a filter to the functions like `{ filter: { exists: "sales" } }` but every place I add the filter it is invalid syntax.

Comment: that's for your answer it's exactly what I'm looking for and you have shown me that crafting complex queries might be a little trickier than I first thought, I'm going to study up. Thanks once again!